# Save pathoverlay in Bundle and retrieve

Tags: android, android-activity, osmdroid

I am trying to come up with a map showing the path traveled of a object.

I have used OSMDroid and pathOverlay for the same. I have successfully implemented that, but it goes once I press back. I want to retain the path and looked up for available options.

The savedInstanceState was something similar to what I was looking for.

I tried the following code:

```
static final String STATE_PATH = "objPath";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        // Restore value of members from saved state
        savedInstanceState = savedInstanceState.getBundle(STATE_PATH);
    } else {

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_location);

    ...

    defineMap();

    ...

    pathOverlay = new PathOverlay(Color.RED, this);

    }
}


@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Save the user's current game state
    //savedInstanceState.putAll(savedInstanceState);
    savedInstanceState.putBundle(STATE_PATH, savedInstanceState);

    // Always call the superclass so it can save the view hierarchy state
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

This doesn't seem to work. Can someone point out to where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

osmdroid overlays are not Parcelable. This means that you cannot put an overlay in a bundle.

The solution is to define your own classes to store your "data model". Then build your pathoverlay from this data model everytime it's needed. 
As this data model will be your own classes, you can define them as Parcelable, and put them in Bundles.